# Form.Control type password in React-Bootstrap always renders an default password that i can't remove

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I am doing the login page and i realized i cannot set the default values of the Form.Control type password input!!!

```
class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: 'thisIsMyDefaultPassword',
      isLoading: false,
      redirectToReferrer: false
    };
  }


  handleChange = name => event => {
    let update = {};
    update[`${name}`] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(update);
  }

  handleFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ password: '' });
  }

  handleSubmit = () => event => {
    let data = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    this.props.login(data)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    let { currentUser } = this.props;
    console.log('currentUser ', currentUser, 'prevProps.currentUser ', prevProps.currentUser );
    if (JSON.stringify(prevProps.currentUser) !== JSON.stringify(currentUser)) {
      console.log('currentUser !=');
      if (currentUser._id) {
        this.setState({
          redirectToReferrer: true
        })
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { email, password , isLoading, redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
console.log('password when rendered', password);
    if (redirectToReferrer) {
        return <Redirect to={'/'} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="loginWrapper">
        <div className="loginContainer">
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="formGroupEmail">
              <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={this.handleChange('email')}
                placeholder="Enter Email"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="formGroupPassword">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                defaultValue={this.state.password}
                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                onChange={this.handleChange('password')}
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            size="lg"
            disabled={isLoading}
            onClick={this.handleSubmit()}
            block
          >
            {isLoading ? 'Loading…' : 'LOGIN'}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

i expect the default values rendered to be controlled by the default state of my component. But it just don't work. I have tried defaultValue / value / and defaultValue with value. but there is still this default number being rendered in the password input .. The above are my latest codes i am still facing the problem although i crack it with onFocus. If there's any better improvement to my codes please comment below too. An Advance thank you to all commenters. really appreciate the help of this community.

Below are the console logs for console.log('password when rendered', password) IT shows that react-bootstrap javascript is clearning the password and setting as 0346:

```
password when rendered thisIsMyDefaultPassword
Login.js:51 password when rendered 
Login.js:51 password when rendered 0346
```

Thus concluding that the defaultValue for the type password does not work ?

Answer (score 3):

The value props is too much here, if you get rid of it, you can change the input. 
Additionally, you always provide the string "password" to your onChange handler as a value. This might not be what you want to do, but instead using the actual password the user is entering.

In your render method:

```
<p>Current password: {this.state.password}</p>
<Form>
  <Form.Group controlId="formGroupPassword">
    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      type="password"
      defaultValue={this.state.password}
      onChange={this.handleChange('password')}
      placeholder="Password"
    />
  </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

And your handleChange function could look like:

```
handleChange = name => event => {
  this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
};
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/8x8zw28nv2

Comment: hey man , my code is exactly same as yours except i declared the state in a constructor. i tried your way by just declaring state as a variable in the class but it didnt worked for me..

Comment: Here a tip: Try to log the password with console.log. This will help you to understand where your problem is. I would add the console.log in the handleChange function (see whether you get the correct value there) and in the render function. Especially I would just do a console.log(this.state) to see where stuff is saved.

Comment: hi grenzbotin, i did a console log on the render function, it shows correctly whatever i input in the field, somehow react-bootstrap jsut overwrites it even though i stated a default value to be the state's password

Comment: i will update the logs i found in my post. @grenzbotin

Comment: Where does it overwrite? Can you update your code in the first post so that we know which line outputs which logging in the console?
I don't really get what your problem is: so, the state gets updated correctly (you see it in your logs.) But what happens then and what should happen instead?

Comment: What are you doing in between these console logs? Assumption for the clearing part: It might be cleared because your "onFocus" function is actually clearing the password state?

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of valued components(TextField, Checkbox, etc.):

1. **Controlled** - The component whose value is controlled by the code implementation. In this type of component you have to set `value` prop of the component with the value source and handle it's `onChange` to get the value and update in the future source.

   `<TextField value={this.state.password}
      onChange={(event) => this.setState({ password: event.target.value })}
   />`
2. **Un-controlled** - The component which has a default value and that value can changed without any trigger/handling in the component code. These components have a prop 'defaultValue' populated with the initial value you want to assign.

   `<TextField defaultValue={this.state.password} />`

> **You can't use both `value` and `defaultValue` on same component.**

In your case You have to remove `defaultValue` prop, as you need a controlled component to make its value persist.

Comment: <Form.Control
                type="password"
                value={password}
                onFocus={this.handleFocus()}
                onChange={this.handleChange('password')}
                placeholder="Password"
              />

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isLoading: false,
      redirectToReferrer: false
    };

Comment: but when rendered still has a default password ... =[

Comment: i tried all combinations individually and both of them together.

Comment: remove this onFocus thing on password and try again!

Answer (score 1):

You have the same value for `defaultValue` and `value`, seems like it doesn't make sense because if `value` has a value, that value will be rendered. Try matching defaultValue to another value or just remove `defaultValue`.
Does your onChange work? Seems like not. Are you implemented your `handleChange`? Because you are using controlled inputs.
Try this:

```
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
        password: e.target.value
    })
  }

  <Form>
    <Form.Group controlId="formGroupPassword">
      <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="Password"
       />
    </Form.Group>
  </Form>
```

Comment: my on change does work but i should edit my code as that it not what im using.. uhh i tried all combinations defaultValue / value / defaultValue and Value